# finding the line number of a coffescript error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, coffeescript

I am trying to find a good way to debug my coffeescript in Rails. My configuration settings for assets  are :

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false
# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

When I have errors in my coffeescript files such as `wepic.js.coffee.erb` after doing a `rake assets:precompile` task, the only debugging information i get is the error type and the filename :

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: unexpected TERMINATOR
(in /home/jtestard/projects/git/webdamsystem/app/assets/javascripts/wepic.js.coffee.erb)
```

Sometimes this is not enough to spot the error quickly and I was trying to get a better trace with maybe the line/column number. Does anyone know of a way to get this type of information?

Answer (score 3):

If you have NPM/NodeJS installed (and `npm install coffee-script -g`), you can try compiling with `coffee -c <filename>` to see the line number. Textmate/Sublime also have plugins where you can see the compiled output of a coffescript file with a key combination, but they require NodeJS/NPM installed as well.

Comment: Ok i'll try that. Do you know any native rails way to do so? This seems to be a common concern for rails developers who use coffeescript

Comment: Does it work fine without pre-compilation? You have an .erb extension, does that mean you are injecting ruby variables into the script and are they available at the time of asset pre-compilation?

Answer (score 0):

The `SyntaxError: unexpected TERMINATOR` error typically occurs when you have TAB characters in your CoffeeScript source file.

You can search for tab characters in your terminal like this:  `$ grep $'\t' FILE_NAME`

Once you find the file(s) with the TAB characters replace them with spaces.

You'll also need to set your source code editor's preferences to use spaces for TABS.